# How to get value from object in twig template file?

Tags: 8, theming

I can print the result object by `{{ dump(item.value['#result']) }}` in theme `item-list--search-results.html.twig` template file.

[image]

I want to print the body field value("body"=>"value") from the object.

How I will do ? I have tried some other ways which I know

- `{{ dump(item.value['#result']['node'].#values['body'][0]['value']) }}`
- `{{ dump(item.value['#result']['node']['#values']['body'][0]['value']) }}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For normal fields you can get the field value by appending the property name `.value`:

```
{% set node = item.value['#result']['node'] %}

{{ node.field_foo.value }}
```

For the body field you need an extra step to process the stored text format:

```
{{ {
  '#type': 'processed_text',
  '#text': node.body.value,
  '#format': node.body.format,
} }}
```

Comment: It's worked for me, thanks!